# Starting a new program with java

Tags: java, class

I am trying to create a program like this below in eclipse, but it shows an error. I'm new to java, so could some one help me in fixing it up and reason why it shows an error ?

```
public class Specifiers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        public void start1()
        {
            System.out.println("In Start Method");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: your `start1()` must be declared within the class body, not the body of an other method (`main`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a method declaration within a method. Try this:

```
public class Specifiers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start1();
    }

    public static void start1()
    {
        System.out.println("In Start Method");
    }
}
```

Edit: of course, it needs to be static. My bad...

Answer (score 6):

You have a method in a method in a class. `start1` should be in the class (not the method) and you want to *call* it from the `main` method.

Also, you need to create an *instance* of your class in order to access non-static methods. Non-static methods can access the individual state (fields) of an instance, so you need to construct one first using a constructor. I suggest you learn more about the concept of classes and instances in object-oriented programming.

```
public class Specifiers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Specifiers x = new Specifiers();
        x.start1();
    }

    public void start1() {
        System.out.println("In Start Method");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for using an instance - this is a better approach than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have methods within methods in Java

This will work:

```
public class Specifiers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("In Start Method");
    }
}
```

or this

```
public class Specifiers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Specifiers( ).start1( );
    }

    public void start1()
    {
      System.out.println("In Start Method");

    }
}
```

Comment: @user1396008: as long as the method belongs to an instance (= not static), it needs an instance to be called on.

Answer (score 1):

The `main` method is the first method, which the Java Virtual Machine executes.
When you execute a class with the Java interpreter, the runtime system starts by calling the class's `main()` method. The `main()` method then calls all the other methods required to run your application. It can be said that the main method is the entry point in the Java program and a Java program can't run without this method

```
public class FirstClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Specifiers x = new Specifiers();
        x.start1();
    }
}

public class Specifiers {

    public void start1() {
        System.out.println("In Start Method");
    }
}
```